# How Can I change the property of components of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-state

I am new to React and recently started working on it. I know that we cannot change the components properties using the props.

I want to know how can  we change the properties of Component?
Below is my code:

Courses.jsx

```
function Courses(){


return (
    <div className="courses">
        <h1>Ongoing Courses</h1>
        <div className="row">
        
        {CourseData.map((value,index)=>{
            return   (
              
                  <div className="col-md-3">
                  <Card title={value.title}  completed={value.completed} content={value.content} value="Resume !" key={index} id={index} />
                  </div>
             
            );
        })}
    </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Here above i am having a Array of Data named as courseData, I am mapping it on a Card component.

Card.jsx:

```
function Card(props){

function handleClick(){
  
}
return (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
            <h2 className="card-title">{props.title}</h2>
            {props.content}
            <br/>
        <button  className="btn btn-danger" > {props.value}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

the CourseData has following properties :

```
courseData : [{
key, 
title,
completed
content}]
```

I simply want that when ever the button present is card gets clicked then the completed attribute of courseData changed to some different value that is passed through the props .

I have tried a lot but not able to do .

Any help regarding this will be helpful for me .

courseData.jsx:

```
const notes = [{
key: 1,
title: "some Text",
completed:false,
content: "some Text"
},
 {
    key: 2,
   title: "some Text",
completed:false,
content: "some Text"
 }]
export default notes;
```

Comment: Where did you declare the `CourseData`? Can you share it ?

Comment: hey @Arnab the courseData is like :const notes = [{
    key: 1,
    title: "Delegation",
    completed:false,
    content: "Q. How many programmers does it take to change a light bulb? A. None – It’s a hardware problem"
},
{
    key: 2,
    title: "Loops",
    completed:false,
    content: "How to keep a programmer in the shower forever. Show him the shampoo bottle instructions: Lather. Rinse. Repeat."
}]

Comment: Is CourseData a state variable?

Comment: Yeah I see it but where did you declare it? is it a state of `Courses.jsx`

Comment: Hey I have added the courseData.jsx file above , you can see there .It is simple Array file for data .

Comment: @AshishKumarGupta I see the structure. But in which file did you declare it? in `course.jsx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CourseData to the state of the Courses component. Then add a method to adjust the data there. Pass the method throught props that will be called when clicking button in the Card component:

```
function Courses() {
  const [courseData, setCourseData] = useState(CourseData);
  const updateCourseData = (index) => {
    courseData.splice(index, 1);  
    setCourseData(courseData);
  }

  return (
    <div className="courses">
      <h1>Ongoing Courses</h1>
      <div className="row">
    
      {courseData.map((value,index)=>{
        return   (
          
              <div className="col-md-3">
              <Card title={value.title} updateCourseData={updateCourseData}  completed={value.completed} content={value.content} value="Resume !" key={index} id={index} />
              </div>
         
          );
      })}
      </div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

in the Card.jsx:

```
<button onClick={() => props.updateCourseData(props.id)}  className="btn btn-danger" > {props.value}</button>
```

Comment: Hey , this solution does not work for me . Could clarify more on, how we would use this  :-    const updateCourseData = (item) => {
    //update course data here (newCourseData) and update the state then
    setCourseData(newCourseData);
  } to update data ?

Comment: I am getting this error - t assign to read only property 'title' of object '#<Object>' i have written this : -      function updateCourseData(data){
        data.title = "ye";
        setCourseData(data);

    }

Comment: It really depends on what do you want to do once clicking the button. Let's say you need to remove that course item. then you can do like this:
```
const updateCourseData = (index) => {
    courseData.splice(index, 1);
    setCourseData(courseData);
  }
```

in the Card.jsx need to pass index: `onClick={() => props.updateCourseData(props.id)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Courses(){
const [coursesData, setCoursesData] = useState(CourseData)

return (
    <div className="courses">
        <h1>Ongoing Courses</h1>
        <div className="row">
        
        {coursesData.map((value,index)=>{
            return   (
                  <div className="col-md-3">
                  <Card coursesData={coursesData}  setCoursesData={setCoursesData} title={value.title}  completed={value.completed} content={value.content} value="Resume !" key={index} id={index} />
                  </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
    </div>
);
```

```
function Card({id,title,value,content,coursesData,setCoursesData }){

function handleClick(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  setCoursesData(coursesData => {
      const data = coursesData
      data.splice(id,1,{
          title: title,
          completed: value,
          content: content,
          key: id
      })
      return data
  })
}
return (
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
            <h2 className="card-title">{title}</h2>
            {content}
            <br/>
        <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-danger">{value}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: when ever I click the button then the value of props.completed in Card.jsx get changed to some next value , so that I can use this changed value of courseData,jsx with some function later outside the Card.jsx . I think it will be clear now .

Comment: You can't mutate the data in components. It`s a bad practice. I will update head comment to working version